# Алгоритм распознавания картинок по шаблону

Tags: алгоритм

Возможно кто-то сталкивался с подобным, или просто читал.
В базе куча картинок с цветами и просто объектами, и вот я загружаю картинку кирпича и алгоритм обойдя все картинки пишет что это кирпич. Даю картинку цвета автомобиля и выдают 3 максимальных совпадения если не найден 100% результат.

Comment: - Умение **точно** сформулировать задачу чрезвычайно полезно в профессии разработчика.

- Думаю, что вам стоит копать в сторону классификаторов изображений и `feature-matching'а` с помощью `SIFT/SURF/ORB`. Можете начать изучение с библиотеки `OpenCV`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@Mirdin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/7200/mirdin) (исчерпал лимит комментариев)

- Термин *"элементарная"* был употреблен в значении *"легко реализуется с хорошим процентом распознавания".*
- В своих ответах я исхожу не из каких-то теоретических знаний, полученных путем чтения википедии, а из вполне себе практических соображений.
- Для задачи, которую вы поставили (`flower1.tiff, flower2.jpg, flower3.jpg`) математический аппарат уже разработан, варианты решения и набор формализованных подходов уже присутствует, поэтому что-то там *"разрабатывать"* равносильно изобретению велосипеда.
- И да, я обратил внимание на расширения.

> - Ради эксперимента вы можете попробовать описанный мной набор действий на практике (заресайзить изображения до, скажем, `32x32 px` и взять усредненную метрику `Euclidean Distance` в `color` спейсе).
> - Для изображений, полученных из одного исходного изображение значения метрики почти наверняка не будут превышать нескольких процентов, что даст нам возможность ответить **"скорее всего, да"** для них и **"нет"** - для других.
> - Дальше *"скорее всего, да"* можно усилить и превратить в *"почти наверняка да"* путем применения более изощренных методов, о некоторых из которых я уже упомянул.

Comment: jpg - формат сжатия с потерей информации, применили как минимум два раза, плюс шум от изменения размеров (в общем случае мы не можем сказать обрезали от рисунка что-нибудь или добавили и изменили размеры, или например деформировал - визуально больших отличий мы не заметим) - и при этом всего несколько процентов, по моему вы спорите ради спора. Я пытаюсь объяснить что не все что кажется одинаковым нам таковым будет для ваших алгоритмов.

Comment: @Mirdin Окей, а вы в своих утверждениях о некорректности/сложности описываемых алгоритмов опираетесь на какой-то практический опыт в области классификаторов/матчеров/`Computer Vision` вцелом или же вы теоретизируете?

Comment: Какой-то бестолковый тред. Если вам нужно реально сравнить три одинаковых картинки в разных форматах, сделайте скриншот и просто попиксельно сравните. Если они разных размеров и нужно много сравнивать определите хэш функцию от пикселей и сравните хэш. Эта задача тривиальна и не требует сверхзнаний математики. Хэш функцию берите из уже существующих.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать - тот пример что я привел, похож на реальные тесты в одном проекте с которым я работал. Но это действительно было довольно давно -- можете смело считать, что теоретизирую.

@igumov рисунок который деформировали а потом конвертировали в другой формат может доставить вам много интересных моментов.

Answer (score -1):

Это очень непростая задача, на данный момент не имеющая "хорошего" алгоритма. Сравнительно недавно Гугль гордо рапортовал о том-что они научили компьютер распознавать кошку, а вы уже хотите произвольную картинку.

Comment: Произвольную, с учетом того, что она есть в базе. Можно же на основе количества цветов, геометрических фигур и прочего попытаться пролистать все картинки в базе? :)

Comment: Да все эти задачи так или иначе решаются уже лет 10. Вопрос только во времени обучения классификатора или времени, затраченном на поиск и матчинг `features` для изображений. Понятно, что стопроцентного результата невозможно достичь, но для многих задач получение правильных результатов в `95-97%` случаев - это вполне реально.

Comment: Так вопрос то как-раз во времени обучения, оно на данный момент очень велико, если не примитизировать задачу -- оставить от рисунка несколько геометрических фигур, или вообще точек, сделать фиксированный размер рисунка, в частном, на конкретной задаче это возможно. 
95-97%, не то что бы вполне реально, это скорее шикарное достижение, 70% -- это уже очень хороший результат.

Comment: @Mirdin Я не знаю, что можно ответить на этот ваш комментарий, но правильные запросы к гуглу (`OpenCV, SIFT, SURF, ORB, feature matching`) я вам указал. Дальше, в общем-то, что-то обсуждать мне кажется бессмысленным :)

Comment: Хорошо, у Вас имеется 3 файла: flower_1.tif (1024х768), flower_2.jpg (640х480, 20%), flower_3.jpg(600х440, 40%). Второй получен из первого, третий из второго. Визуально одна и та же картинка - вы уверены что найдется алгоритм который их сопоставит и будет работать на других тройках изображений, например с котиком или машиной. Я не отрицаю, что в этом направлении наработано много технологий, но пока я не был бы очень оптимистичным.

Comment: @Mirdin

- Эта задача элементарна - вам нужно определить *достаточно хорошую* метрику одинаковости изображений, не зависящую от их размеров. Дальше вы попарно (можно кстати, быстрее, чем за `O(n^2)`, но это уже отдельная история) считаете эти метрики и определяете некоторый *порог схожести,* то есть то значение метрики, после которого изображения начинают считаться разными.

- Все, дело в шляпе.

Comment: - Примеров таких метрик много - начиная от банальной попиксельной разницы изображений, уменьшенных до `n x n` пикселей, заканчивая [специальными хэшами](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120562/) и метриками, построенными на пресловутых `SIFT / SURF / ORB` и гистограммах ориентированных градиентов.

- Метрика выбирается в зависимости от степени точности, которую вы хотите получить и необходимости учитывать трансформации.

- Для вашей задачи (найти одинаковые заресайзенные изображения) подойдет даже простая `difference-`метрика.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать - вы не обратили внимания на расширения файлов. И да элементарная, не значит простая, найти простые делители произвольного числа, то же элементарная задача. Похоже мы с вами друг друга не понимаем. Если вы думаете что я не допускаю решения задачи в первом сообщении, то ошибаетесь. Просто для этого ТС придется разработать довольно внушительный мат.аппарат - за который лично я бы не взялся. Да технологии которые вы указываете будут только первой ступенькой.

Comment: @Mrdin, несколько не по теме, но интересно. Я уже несколько раз видел высказывания типа

    Гугль гордо рапортовал о том-что они научили компьютер распознавать кошку

Интересно же то, что (насколько я понял) они **не учили распознавать кошку**, а нейронная сеть **сама** почему-то выделила  изображения кошек (именно их) из остальных изображений.

Понимаете разницу?

Comment: @avp Ну если строго придираться к словам, то и не компьютер, а "программу"... Но в результате могут выделять произвольные изображения кошек - так что результат есть.

Comment: @Mirdin, да не к словам (компьютер, программа ...) я придираюсь, а к *смыслу высказывания*. К тому, что не **научили**, а **сама научилась**. 

Вот это и поражает. Интересно было бы где-нибудь поподробнее про этот эксперимент почитать.